# Changing ylim while looping

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I have from dataframe

```
time= 11.0, 11.3, 11.4, 21.0, 22.0 22.1, 98.0, 98.1, 98.2 

measurement= 13, 13.5, 13, 15, 16, 15, 14, 12, 14

epoch= [[11.0, 11.3, 11.4], [21.0, 22.0, 22.1], [98.0, 98.1, 98.2]]
```

and I have:

epoch list has same data than `time` but it has been put to sets `[]`  with values that are near each others.

I try to plot time as x and detections as y as many times as there are sets in epoch list. And for each plot I would like to change xlim so it would match min. and max. of each set in epoch list.

`plt.xlim(min(epoch[0])`, `max(epoch[0]))` and the next plot `plt.xlim(min(epoch[1])`, `max(epoch[1]))`

etc until the loop ends and three plots are drawn and whole timeline has been split to three plots.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in epoch:
    #plt.xlim(min(epoch[0]), max(epoch[0])) 
    plt.plot(time, measurement, '.')
    plt.xlabel('time vs detection')
    plt.ylabel('magnitude')
    plt.show()
```

I can make this to draw the plot as many times as there are sets in epoch.

But I would like to limit min and max limits for each plot so they match min and max of each min and max of correct epoch.

Desired end result would be three plots with first covering time period from 11 to 11.4, second having time period from 21 to 22.1 and third having time period from 98 to 98.2

I hope this makes sense!

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your example is confusing, there are not tuples. Please provide an explicit, **minimal** example DataFrame constructor and also minimize `epoch` to keep just enough to serve as an example.

Comment: I have update my answer according to the update in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use your variable i in the loop

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in epoch:
    plt.plot(time, measurement, '.')
    plt.xlabel('time vs detection')
    plt.ylabel('magnitude')
    plt.xlim(min(i), max(i)) 
    plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I literally used 2 days to bang my head against wall for this. Thank you so much for your time. This works well!